# error while instaling odoo custom moduls : AssertionError: Element openerp has extra content: data, line 2

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, assertions

I am trying to install a custom module, then I get the error sign.

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20170818\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 340, in load_modules
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20170818\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 239, in load_marked_modules
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20170818\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 156, in load_module_graph
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20170818\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 98, in _load_data
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20170818\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 849, in convert_file
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20170818\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 919, in convert_xml_import
File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3313, in lxml.etree._Validator.assert_ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:159862)
AssertionError: Element openerp has extra content: data, line 2
```

What type of mistake I did for getting this error.

I am using odoo9 and i have search that it cause by XML file, i have tried to change  into  and delete the  but isn't solve my problem.

thank you in advance.

here my XML file :

```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="purchase_order_form_training" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">purchase.order.form</field>
            <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="amount_tax" position="after">
                    <field name="down_payment" widget="monetary" options="{'currency_field':'currency_id'}"/>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="purchase_order_tree_training" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">purchase.order.tree</field>
            <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_tree"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml"/>     
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: it's done, i found that i write disfunction syntax. Thank you

Comment: You need to post your solution as an Answer for anyone who may have a similar problem in the future.